# OBJ texture issues: halved/triangular faces in Mario Kart Wii

Tags: modeling, export

I've just gotten into modding Mario Kart Wii and I was hoping someone on this end of the 3D modelling process could help me with my texture issue.

For kicks, I found a Thomas the Tank Engine model from a Nintendo 3DS game on a model site. When I first loaded the model into the game, the faces appeared as they do in the photo I've provided. At that point I assumed the polycount needed to be lowered to 1000, so I removed bits from the model to bring it down to 999, and I still have the same problem.

I've just made a model with 12 faces (cube + 6 other colored panels) and again the same result. Hopefully someone out there can enlighten me on the formatting for the model, or whatever I'm missing. This could also be something I'm not getting involving the BRRES model importer for modding Mario Kart.

[image: Models in Blender vs Mario Kart Wii]

Comment: How are you exporting this, what file format are you using and what exporter? It looks like the the importer/engine/editor/whatever you are opening your models with doesn't like quads (four sided faces) very much, only triangles appear to be shown. Some blender exporters (like OBJ) have an option to triangulate the model on export, have you tried exporting with that option ticked?

Comment: I ticked the triangulate faces option and the model looks the way it should. Thank you for your help.